# Autofac + MVC5: Resolving a Service's Dependencies

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, autofac, code-injection

I've gotten the basics done with resolving controller dependencies with Autofac + MVC5.  However, I'm wondering how to inject dependencies into services.

Given a sample definition as such, how can I create/get an instantiated copy of the class with Autofac resolving the necessary dependencies?

```
Bar : IBar
{

  Public Bar(IFoo foo, IPanda panda)

{}


}
```

Comment: There are [few steps](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/mvc.html) to integrate Autofac in MVC. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I have Autofac integrated; I am wondering how to inject dependencies into objects that aren't controllers.

Comment: E.g, injecting Service C with services A and B, so C can do its own thing.

Comment: You should look into service location for that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737139/resolve-instance-autofac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately it just comes down to registering the type in the Container. Such as:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<Bar>().As<IBar>();
var container = builder.Build();
```

I'm assuming you have similar code using the Builder somewhere during your initialization.

There are several different ways to register and configure dependencies, lifetimes, interceptors etc, more info here:
http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/registration.html

Once everything is registered, whenever Autofac tries to instantiate your controller, it'll inspect your controller's constructor, and when it finds an `IBar` as dependency, it'll look for it's container registration and instantiate accordingly.

The same applies when it tries to instantiate `IBar`, it'll notice `IFoo` and `IPanda` and repeat the same process.

The main difference is that Autofac supports automatic registration of your controllers, just to spare you the hassle of registering each one manually.

So in the end, it'll all be chained in that manner, dependencies created as needed. 
I tend to avoid using ServiceLocator style of instantiation by requesting a dependency directly, and just let Autofac provide the dependencies during construction.

Comment: Thank you very much!!  This helped clear a block in my mind.  I'll still have to call "DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IBar>();" to get a copy of the service, but all passed constructor services will be instantiated automatically.  I've been making instantiating copies of the classes themselves, but not actually via the interfaces they implement. This will clean up my code a lot. :)

Comment: Well, you don't necessarily need to call the DependencyResolver. I mean, if your controller has a dependency on a IBar, then it will be provided automatically, no need to call GetService. The same would apply to any sort of chain of dependencies. I usually manage to build the entire app without manually calling GetService, which would be the ServiceLocator way of doing things.

Comment: I was able to purge my code of a lot of "GetService" when I modified the design layout substantially.  Thank you for the advice :)